# How to convert Base64 to image

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, asp.net

I am trying to display image from database. I have converted the database image into base 64 format. I am using JavaScript for the conversion. But its not an image format. My code is as follows:

```
var che = btoa(data.d.ItemImage1);
$('#imgUpload').attr('src', "data:image/png;base64," + che);
```

On alerting this, the format will be as follows, but it cannot show an image.

```
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
```

Comment: What is `data.d.ItemImage`? What its value?

Comment: data.d.itemimage1 is the json function for getting image from database.

Comment: The base64 string does not appear to be valid. I'm unable to create a PNG file from it. How have you created it?

Comment: I have got base64 by using the convert function

Comment: seems invalid base64..

Comment: may be an invalid convertion but i got this by using btoa conversion as mentioned above

Comment: your base64 after decode contains "100,97,116,97,58,105,109,97,103,101,47,106,112,101,103,59,98,97,115,101....

Comment: @ cevek how can i change this to an image format?

Comment: @kannanD.S I am not sure about btoa, but you can directly convert the bytes to base64 by using `"data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(YOUR BYTES)`

Answer (score 0):

for your case try following

```
$('#imgUpload').attr('src', String.fromCharCode.apply(null, data.d.ItemImage1));
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'split'

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

**$('#imgPhoto').attr('src', "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData);** works fine. We are using this.
Check your imageData value(in your case it is data.d.ItemImage1). Check the value using alert.

Comment: I have also tried that already, instead of jpeg I use png. The problem is in the conversion of database format to base64 and to image.